Firebase Clound Functions - Sending message via FCM does not work due to deprecated endpoint
I hope you can help me with this problem. I have a Firebase Cloud Function, which sends a message via FCM to a certain topic when a document is created on the firestore database. Here is my code for it:
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.onWordpressPostCreate = functions.firestore
    .document("wpPosts/{title}")
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

        console.log("-------------start create function-----------------");

        const data = snap.data();
        const title = data.title;
        const excerpt = data.excerpt;

        const payload = {

            notification: {
              title: `Neuer Deal: ${title}`,
              body: excerpt,
              badge: "1",
              sound: "default",
            },

        };


        return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("newDeal", payload)
            .then((response) => {

                console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);

            })
            .catch((error) => {
            console.error("FCM failed", error);
            });
    });

It all worked fine in the past, but today I received an error Message in the Logs of Firebase Cloud functions, that the endpoint would be deprecated.

"message: 'An unknown server error was returned. Raw server response: "{"error":"Deprecated endpoint, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1"}"' "

Is this a known issue? I do not know what I should change in my function, because I do not use a specific HTTP endpoint there. I only use the funtion sendToTopic(). Maybe someone had this problem too and can help me here.
In addition I have to say that sometimes the function works and sometimes I get this error message as kind of a warning that it would not be work in the future at all.
I searched Google for this problem and I found that the Legacy FCM API should be migrated to the HTTP v1. But I do not know how this can affect my function or what I have to change there. In the article of this link it says that I have to change the endpoint and the structure of the body but in Firebase Cloud Functions this is all handled by the FCM functions itself. I only have to call sendToTopic() with payload...

Is your firebase-admin dependency up-to-date? If you're right and you're using still-supported library APIs then I guess you need a version of the firebase-admin library needs updating to use the new endpoints at Firebase's end.

The emails I've been getting about this say you need web FCM SDK >= 9.22.1.

I looked into my package.json file and there it says that my firebase-admin version is at 12.1.0

So did you update it?  Your dependency is a few months old. https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node

And it's probably the firebase dependency not firebase-admin that matters actually.

Yes I updated it to the current version and I did not get the error once more until now.

the sentToTopic method has been deprecated by firebase, you should send topics using the send method and add the topic in the payload like so
{
   topic: "a topic here",
   notification: {
              title: `Neuer Deal: ${title}`,
              body: excerpt,
              badge: "1",
              sound: "default",
  },


Good point, but I'd be surprised if the Firebase packages didn't translate sendToTopic() calls into send() calls rather than deliberately calling a deprecated API endpoint.

Unfortunately, that seems to be the case as at v12.0.0 of the package, unsure about the latest version.

The sendToTopic and sendToDevice methods are deprecated. You should use the following alternatives instead.
for token:
admin.messaging().send({
    token: 'fcm_token',
    notification: {
    title,
    body,
  },
  android: {
    notification: {
      sound: "default"
  }
},
  apns: {
   payload: {
      aps: {
          sound: 'default'
      }
  }
 },
})

for topic:
admin.messaging().send({
    topic: 'topic here',
    ...other property
})


Here's a summary of the key points from the Firebase documentation on migrating from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1:

Migration deadline:

Legacy FCM APIs for HTTP and XMPP were deprecated on June 20, 2023
Shutdown begins on July 22, 2024


Advantages of HTTP v1 API:

Better security with OAuth2 access tokens
More efficient customization of messages across platforms
More extendable and future-proof for new client platforms


Key changes:

New endpoint URL format:
https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-ID/messages:send
Authorization: Use OAuth 2.0 access token instead of server key


Steps to migrate:
a. Update server endpoint
b. Update authorization method
c. Use Application Default Credentials (ADC) or service account for authentication

Authentication options:

Google Application Default Credentials (ADC)
Service account JSON file
Short-lived OAuth 2.0 access token derived from a service account


Code examples provided for:

Using ADC with Admin SDK
Manually providing credentials
Generating access tokens


Important note:

Ensure "Firebase Cloud Messaging API" is enabled in Google Cloud console



For detailed implementation instructions and code samples, refer to the full documentation at the provided URL.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1#

“Steps to migrate: a. Update server endpoint” - OK, but we’re not using the server endpoint directly, we’re using the cloud messaging SDK which we have updated. Shouldn’t the cloud messaging SDK be the one to update which server endpoint it is calling?

don't use old function use the send method.
    console.debug('Sending_FCM', JSON.stringify(message));

    const pushMessage: TokenMessage = {
        token: fcmToken,
        data,
        notification,
        android: {
            notification: {
                icon: 'notification_icon',
                sound: 'default'
            }
        },
        apns: {

        }
    };

    // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided registration token.
    try {
        const msgId: string = await firebaseAdmin
            .messaging()
            .send(pushMessage);
        // .sendToDevice(fcmToken, message);
        console.debug('Successfully sent FCM message', JSON.stringify(pushMessage), JSON.stringify(msgId));

